# How can I highlight paragraphs from text input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting to learn `jQuery` today.  I'm currently on 24th tutorial [PHPachademy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIZFHjkUCrs&feature=BFa&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810).  I'm having a lot of problems getting this particular tutorial to work correctly.  I'm pretty sure it's a semantic error >_<;;

Heres an [Attempt JSfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg72b/6/)

Lastly could someone explain why there this line to me?

```
('" + search_name + "')
```

why are there so many `+`'s and `'"` in the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('#names li').removeClass('highlight');
```

Instead of

```js
$(#names li).removeClass('highlight');
```

You reference the #names variable instead of using the `'#names li'` string

[**Fixed fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg72b/9/)

> Lastly could someone explain why there this line to me?
>   ('" + search_name + "')

`:contains` selector [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.
>   The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, **text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks.** The text must have matching case to be selected.

[**Fiddle without the quotation marks**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg72b/15/)

**By the way, since you're trying to learn jQuery**

An important rule about jQuery is, jQuery shouldn't can can't replace javascript! it's an abstraction library above javascript. Don't over use it, `this.value` can bring you the value of input a lot easier and faster then `$(this).val()`.

[You can read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

Comment: could you accually explain to me why the use of + and '" in that contains()

Comment: @MatthewHarwood. Read the updated answer. The jQuery lib has a wonderful self explained docs site. it's your best new friend!

Comment: arg I hate to be annoying but could you give me a sample of the 'bare word'  I <3 you marking right.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood. I added a fiddle 2 min ago. any way, example: `':contains(foo)'` or `':contains("foo")'`

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: The + concatenates the different elements into one element. Look at Royi Namir's answer for a nice explanation.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl. this wasn't his question. he's asking about the quotes inside the parentheses of `:contains()`

Comment: @MatthewHarwood. I added a best practice note, I hope it will help you in the jquery adventure...

Comment: @gdoron: I refered to `Royi Namir`s answer to add to your already perefect answer for completness.

Answer (score 2):

just add "

```
$("#names li")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg72b/7/

Comment: could you explain the reason for + "' in the contains?()

Comment: + just for concatenate the strings. search_name is the value of input

Comment: @Yorgo. he's not talking about those. `text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. `

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: @MatthewHarwood. if it was C# or Java you should have escaped the quotes so it's even uglier.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing something in the dom jquery always parse a string in the form of

```
$('somethingtosearchfor').doSomethingOnIt()
```

In your case, you are building a jquery line from a search_name variable so you have to do a concatenation (+) between strings that are delimited by ". With this concatenation, you are building the jquery syntax to search in the dom and this syntax must be a string so you concatenate ' chars with your search name to have as a result the same syntax as gdoron mention